# Redis internal representations

Tags: redis

Why do I get the result "raw" from the following?

`redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set massage "hello"
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> object encoding massage
"raw"`

Does it have anything to do with?

`#define REDIS_ENCODING_EMBSTR_SIZE_LIMIT 39`

Answer (score 1):

The 39 is to decide if to embed it or not. If you look at the exact piece of code where the define is it explains it all:

https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/73a809b1591378e1042a1028d0b8e10217e6e7c7/src/object.c#L87

With regards to the raw that is the type for all what you call strings, if it is a valid number representation it is an Int.

Examples:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set str "hello"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> object encoding str
"raw"
127.0.0.1:6379> set int 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> object encoding int
"int"
127.0.0.1:6379> lpush list hello
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> object encoding list
"ziplist"
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd zset 1 1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> object encoding zset
"ziplist"
127.0.0.1:6379> sadd set 1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> object encoding set
"intset"
127.0.0.1:6379> hset hash field value
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> object encoding hash
"ziplist"
```

As you can can see this is how the object is represented internally to Redis.

If you want the actual type you could try the `type` command.

P.S. Please make your question more clear next time. It may also be worth adding references for where you have looked. You can not simply stumble across that `define`

Comment: It's a very good answer. But it's a very good question too, although perhaps not very SO-like. Because it asks "why".

Comment: Yea I did know that. From the question format I presumed this was not meant the way it was asked. But you are correct :-)

Comment: Let's edit the question along the lines "what is the raw encoding"? I'm sure that's what was meant. :)

Comment: Unfortunately i cant suggest edits and I'm on my phone. I'm sure I've been able too in the past. I will try tomorrow

Comment: Same here, on the phone. I will do it tomorrow.